# Making a right triangle in python using loops and calling functions

Tags: python, loops

I am new to python language and I have to create a right triangle that looks like this:
[right triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0duV.png)

I cannot use print statements, I must use a loop, and I have to call functions to complete the loop. The functions are star() which prints a ('*'), space() which prints (' '), and newline() which prints("").

Any and all tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? We're happy to help you with specific problems and questions, but this is not a code-writing service. Consider adding code showing an attempted solution and have a specific portion that you need help with.

Comment: I can do the exact opposite of what I want 
sp = 1
    for i in range(size):
        star()
        sp -= 1

        for j in range(size % size -sp):
            star()
        space()
        newline()

Comment: As per comment from avery, you need to do this yourself and then come back for help - that's the way you will learn. Here is a clue - think about creating a outer loop which is the height of the triangle, then consider what you need to do inside each iteration of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it as a square where each row/column position determines which function to call.  To get a triangle you have to figure out the relationship between the row and column of each position that will produce the desired result.  In your example, you want a star() in positions where the column is greater-equal to the number of remaining rows.  Going through rows in reverse will provide this relationship outright:

```
size = 4
for remainingRows in range(size,0,-1):
    for column in range(1,size+1):
        if column >= remainingRows: star()
        else: space()
    newline()
```

Another way to approach this would be to consider the number of stars that you need to print on each line and call space() for the remainder of the line (before printing the stars).

```
size = 4
for line in range(1,size+1):
    for _ in range(size-line): space()
    for _ in range(line): star()
    newline()
```